# Is there a way to echo a blackslash followed by newline in bash?

Tags: bash, newlines

I’m trying to terminate a line with `\` and have something else on a new line.
At first I did this but it just prints the \n:

```
$ echo -e "Test\\\nNewline" 
Test\nNewline
```

I tried this way but it add a space following the backslash:

```
$ echo -e "Test\\ \nNewline"
Test\ 
Newline
```

How can I do this so there is no space after the `\`?

**UPDATE:** There isn't a problem now as I see that adding two more slash gets the result I want. But I am still wondering why  it does?

```
$ echo -e "Test\\\\\nNewline"
Test\
Newline
```

Comment: I don't know, but something funny about double quotes. Try this `$ echo -e 'tt\\\nP'`

Comment: so take your first example, thst you think should work and doesn't, try changing double quotes to single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Bash Reference Manual: Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html): Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters [including backslash] are removed.

Therefore, `"Test\\\\\nNewline"` is replaced with `Test\\nNewline` before being passed as a parameter to the `echo` command.

To demonstrate this:

```
$ echo -e "Test\\\\\nNewline"
Test\
Newline

$ echo -e 'Test\\\nNewline'
Test\
Newline
```

Comment: no doubt the answer is within those rules, but could you explain how that leads one to how `"\\\\\n"` is required to do backslash new line?  So for example, for those 5 backslashes n (which is in his example), becomes what it becomes.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! You are missing a \ in the single quoted example. ;)

Comment: @InFlames Fixed.

Comment: echo without -e is one thing.. But he did echo -e in his example,  so your demonstration has a result with more backslashes than the result in his example. It'd be interesting if you can explain his example.

Comment: -1  his example was echo -e and double quotes.  Yours has no `-e`

Comment: @Steven i'd like to see "how bash changes the parameter sent to echo" with his example and his example used `-e`

Comment: @Steven The operation of echo is different with and without the -e, though your explanation remained the same.  All you did was you copy/pasted the result with -e and your explanation remained the same. And you haven't stated whether your explanation "Therefore, "Test\\\\\nNewline" is replaced with Test\\nNewline "  applies to the case of the -e or not. Since your earlier answer gave the case without -e and your newer answer gives the case with, why don't you explain for both cases instead of altering your answer to only show one. i.e. don't delete an example from your answer

Comment: @barlop Why don't you edit the answer how you see fit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26757/discussion-between-barlop-and-steven).

Comment: Let's not.  I am satisfied with my answer as-is.  If you are not, edit the answer.  You have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Steven's already explained why so many backslashes are necessary; I'd like to list some possibly-better ways to do the same thing. First, using single-quotes instead of double-quotes skips the extra level of escape interpretation/removal:

```
$ echo -e "Test\\\nNewline"
Test\nNewline
$ echo -e 'Test\\\nNewline'
Test\
Newline
```

Second, I recommend against using `echo` for things like this, since different versions of it behave quite differently: some will interpret escape sequences in the string (like `\n`) even without the `-e` option, some will print the "-e" as part of their output, etc. Here's an example using /bin/echo instead of the bash builtin version:

```
$ /bin/echo -e 'Test\\\nNewline'
-e Test\\\nNewline
```

...That's on OS X v10.10.4; it may be different on your OS and/or version. Anytime you want predictable behavior with escape interpretation and/or leaving off the final linefeed, I recommend `printf` instead of `echo`. It's a little more complicated: the first argument to `printf` is a format string, in which escapes are *always* interpreted, and that can also include `%` sequences that'll be used to add in the remaining arguments (in which escape sequences are *not* interpreted). Also, `printf` doesn't automatically add a linefeed at the end, you have to include that explicitly. Here are a couple of ways to print what you want with `printf`:

```
$ printf 'Test\\\nNewline\n'    # note explicit final newline
Test\
Newline
$ printf '%s\n' 'Test\' 'Newline'    # Escape is interpreted in the format string, but not in the second argument
Test\
Newline
```

Comment: It's annoying though that while they called it printf, it is quite different to the printf in C. For example this works in C ` printf("%d",'A');` it prints 65. Whereas with *nix printf, you can do $ printf '%s' 'A' But you can't do $ printf '%d' 'A'

Comment: @barlop That's not really a difference in `printf`, it's a result of the shell not using the same type system that C does. (Actually, the shell doesn't have much of a type system at all.) In both C and shell, the `%d` format spec expects an integer, but C and bash have very different ideas of what constitutes an integer. In C, `'A'`  is a char, which is an integer type, and has the value 65. (`"A"`, on the other hand, is an array of char, which is a very different thing.) Bash doesn't really have an integer type, it just has strings, but a string consisting of digits is also an integer.

Comment: @barlop Now, having said that, there is a hack. Bash's `printf` will treat a string that starts with a single-quote as a C-style char. So `printf '%d' "'A"` will print "65".

Comment: how far do the hacks go, for example, how about a hack for this `printf("%c",65);`  printing A

Comment: @barlop That direction's ickier. You have to use two calls to `printf`: one with `%o` to convert to octal, then put that after a backslash in a second call to it'll be treated as an octal-based character escape sequence. `printf \\$(printf '%03o' 65)` will do it. See [BashFAQ #71: How do I convert an ASCII character to its decimal (or hexadecimal) value and back?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) for more variations.